# VB2008 DefaultCellStyle.Format の設定が反映されない

Tags: winforms, vb.net

DataGridView で、小数点以下2桁を表示させたいのですが、うまくいきません。

---

```
Protected Sub InitializeControlDataGridView_dgvXyz()
    Try
        With Me.dgvGosa()
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None

            ' 初期化
            .DataSource = Nothing

            ' 列幅の設定
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.Feed).Width = 100
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.StartPoint).Width = 150
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.MidPoint).Width = 150
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.EndPoint).Width = 150

            Me.InitializeControlDataGridView_dgvXyzHeaderText()

            ' 表示フォーマットの設定
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.StartPoint).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F2"
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.MidPoint).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.MidPoint).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0.00"
            .Columns(EnumColOrder.EndPoint).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
後略
```

---

```
Protected Function GetDataSource() As DataSet
    Try
(中略)
            Dim addRow As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow

            addRow(EnumColOrder.Feed) = record.RNo
            addRow(EnumColOrder.StartPoint) = CType(record.XCoordinates, Double)
            addRow(EnumColOrder.MidPoint) = CType(record.YCoordinates, Double)
            addRow(EnumColOrder.EndPoint) = CType(record.ZCoordinates, Double)

            dataTable.Rows.Add(addRow)
```

---

ぐぐってみたところ、`DefaultCellStyle`は値が`string`では反映されないとのことで、`Double`にキャストしている(つもり)なんですが、表示結果は小数点以下を表示しません。

たぶん初歩的なところで間違っていると思いますので、コメントいただける方、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `DataRow`のセッターは値の暗黙変換が効きますが、`DataColumn`の型を`String`から`Double`に変更していますか？

Comment: .Columns(EnumColOrder.MidPoint).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                .Columns(EnumColOrder.MidPoint).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0.00"
=========
と書いてみたのですが、「'DataType'は'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn'のメンバではありません。」と出ます。

どこにどのように書けばいいか、ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

型付データセットデザイナーを使用した場合の`DataColumn.DataType`の変更方法です。

[image: 型付データセットデザイナー]

1. (ない場合)プロジェクトにデータセットを追加します。
2. データセットに既存の`DataTable`(ここではOriginalRecord)と同じスキーマのテーブル(例：ConvertedRecord)を作成します。
3. 型を変更する列(例：ConvertedRecord.XCoordinates)を選択し、`DataType`に`System.Double`を選択します。(変更しない列も元のテーブルと同じ`DataType`であることを確認します。)

値を移し替える場合は以下のようにします。

```
' Dim originalTable As DataTableが引数
Dim convertedTable As New SomeDataSet.ConvertedRecordDataTable()
For Each sr As DataRow In originalTable.Rows
    Dim dr = convertedTable.NewRow()
    dr.ItemArray = sr.ItemArray
    convertedTable.Rows.Add(dr)
End For

' DataSourceにconvertedTableを設定する
```

また読み取り専用であれば`DataColumn.Expression`を使用する手もあると思います。

### 動的にスキーマを変更する場合

`DataTable.Clone()`を用いるとテーブルの構造がコピーできます。レコードがなければ`DataColumn.DataType`の値を変更できるので、

```
Dim convertedTable = originalTable.Clone()
convertedTable.Columns(1).DataType = GetType(Double)
' Columnsを変更したら上のFor Eachでデータを移す
```

のように変更後のテーブルを実行時に構成することができます。

Comment: すみません、初心者の質問で。

1. (ない場合)プロジェクトにデータセットを追加します。
↑
やりました。

2. データセットに既存のDataTable(ここではOriginalRecord)と同じスキーマのテーブル(例：ConvertedRecord)を作成します。
↑
OriginalRecordテーブルが存在しません。
いまここでつまずいています。
単純にDataSetを追加しただけでは、OriginalRecordと関連付けがされていないと思います。
どのようにしてOriginalRecordのDataTableを作成するのでしょうか?

ご教示お願いします。

Comment: @MaFengLing OriginalRecordテーブルは既存の`DataTable`を表しています。変換後のテーブルさえ定義できれば無くても特に問題ありません。しかし既存のコードで型付`DataSet`を使用していないのであればあえて追加せずに`Clone()`等の使用を検討したほうがよいかもしれません。

Comment: pgrho さん、お付き合いありがとうございます。
解決しました。

まず、DataSet がプロジェクトにありました。
OriginalRecordがありました。(他のオブジェクトに隠れていました。)
OriginalRerordのColumn(num).DataType = System.Double に変更したらうまくいきました。

見当外れな質問をしてすみませんでした。
お付き合いありがとうございました。